# javascript won't trigger when including in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I've changed the theme to my Wordpress page and suddenly the javascript wouldn't be triggered for a text field with onChange. I've checked the folders several times and it seems to be right. I'm new to jquery but I read that WordPress uses it a lot and it's much easier, but that I don't know how to use (jet...) If you have any creative solution for my problem, let me know! ;)
When I build it to another page, without WordPress, it works fine...

Text field:

```
<div id="form_box"><span id="CorrectNameHint"></span>
<input class="" placeholder="Förnamn" type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange="CorrectName(this.value)" value="<?php echo($_GET["name2"]); ?>" />
</div>
```

Header included in header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../panel/forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

Script in forms.js

```
function CorrectName(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("CorrectNameHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("CorrectNameHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","panel/validate_user.php?name="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Text from validate_user.php if the name isn't empty

```
if(isset($_GET["name"])){       
    if($_GET["name"] != ""){
        echo("<IMG SRC='../panel/bilder/green_check.png'>");
        $_SESSION["Registreraname"] = 1;
    } else {
        echo("<IMG SRC='../panel/bilder/denied.png'>");
        $_SESSION["Registreraname"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right path to your `js` file? Can you see any errors on your console?

Comment: Wordpress already has `jQuery` included and I think it overwrites the `$` to `jQuery`, so try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in your code and don't include any scripts for it, it should be loaded by default ( you can check that in the console too )

Comment: Why do you use jQuery and implement ajax manually?